# How do I fix? Error: Select is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'

Tags: .net, vb.net, .net-2.0, sorting

Keep getting error: 'Select' is not a member of 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of String)'.

I am rendering x86 and using framework 2.0 (as its unnecessary for the direct player I'm using)

How do I fix this? or is there another method of doing this?

The purpose of this function is simply to sort an array.

[image]

Code:

```
Position15 = Sortlinks(Position15)

    End Sub
    Private Function Sortlinks(ByVal Info As List(Of String))
        Dim order() As Integer = Info.Select(Function(s) If(s.Contains("Facebook.com"), 0, If(s.Contains("Twitter.com"), 1, If(s.Contains("MySpace.com"), 2, If(s.Contains("Youtube.com"), 3, If(s.Contains("Linkedin.com"), 4, -1)))))).ToArray
        Dim temp() As String = Info.ToArray

        Array.Sort(order, temp)
        Info = temp.ToList
        Return Info
    End Function
```

Comment: Do you have `Imports System.Linq` in the class file?

Answer (score 2):

`Select` is a LINQ extension method, which was introduced in .NET 3.5, so it's not available for .NET 2.0. You'll have to target .NET Framework 3.5 or higher in order to use it.

Comment: is there another method to sort a list to accomplish what I have done above then?

Comment: @Santa: simply use [`List.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx).

Comment: how do I define the order like above then?

Comment: @Santa You'll have to rewrite this code yourself - it should be fairly simple. If you're not sure what `Select` does, you can [have a look at the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx).

Comment: Do you mind giving me an example? Sorry to sound dim but I'm a little stuck.